# Is it possible to rename file name with MD5 hash encoding in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have this scenario where I have a blob with multiple binary files and I would like to copy these files into another blob storage using Azure data factory.
The issue is my destination file name should be MD5 encoded . Now I would like to know if it is possible in ADF to change the file name to MD5 encoded type in destination and if yes can someone outline the steps on how to do it.

I can copy the files but i cant rename it to MD5 encoding.

Waiting for experts comments!!!

Thanks
zzz

Comment: As I know about DF, no, we can't. The file name doesn't support the `MD5` expression, only support `GUID()`. Some Ideas are that you may try it with code level.

Comment: Hi @ankit, may I post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know about DF, no, we can't.

The file name doesn't support MD5 expression or functions, it only support GUID(). Some Ideas are that you may try it with code level.

Ref: [Expressions and functions in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions)